# R: File format for a data.table with a column containing vectors as elements

Tags: c++, r, file, format

From a C++ program, I would like to write a file that I can read from R. I would like to read this file as a data.frame with two columns, one containing integers and another one containing a a vector of float numbers. What format (and associated R read command), would you advice me to use?

Note that the files are going to be quite big (tens of GB) and I will need to write and read a few hundreds of them. So performance matters. Something like

```
FirstValue otherValues
10 {0.02 0.01 0.53 0.03}
15 {0.02 0.9}
18 {0.76 0.3 0.78}
28 {0.03 0.5 0.32 0.12 0.28}
```

would be a practical format as my data is stored in C++ in a format of the kind `std::vector<std::pair<size_t, std::vector<float>>> data`, were `data[i].first` is the "FirstValue" of the `i`th row and `data[i].second` is the "otherValues" for the `i`th row.

Comment: I'd have the C++ program write into a database and then query the database from R.

Comment: What do you mean by "database"? I'll have a folder in which I collect those files. The question is about the format. Because it represents a fair amount of data, I would like to print those data on files so that I can fetch them when the R program needs it.

Comment: By "datebase" I mean something like PostgreSQL. I didn't specify further because that's not my area of expertise and databases with better performance are probably available. The amount of data you plan to produce should be stored within a relational database and not a collection of files.

Comment: Alternatively exporting the data as `json` or `xml` should work. Both can be read into R. Packages that would be of help are `jsonlite` or `xml2`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in R you will do something with the list of values in the *otherValues* column. If so and if performance is an issue, I would write the values in the *otherValues* as separate rows, like:

```
FirstValue otherValues
10 0.02
10 0.01
10 0.53
10 0.03
15 0.02
15 0.9
18 0.76
...
```

Than in R, using the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
txt <- fread('data.txt', sep= '\t', colClasses= c('integer64', 'numeric'), header= TRUE, nThread= 1)
```

`sep` is the column separator and `header=TRUE` means the first row is the header.
I think is quite important to set `colClasses= ...` so R doesn't have to guess. `nThread= 1` is the number of threads, try and see what's best.

I doubt that parsing the list of floats like `{0.02 0.01 0.53 0.03}` within R will be faster than the above. Similarly, I doubt that passing by json format or external databases would make things faster.

Comment: The problem is that long format needs a significant amount of additional disk space.